# Setting up a click listener on a button within a RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have it clicked and it gets up to it and shows the right getText() method but the setText method is not working...

```
userAdapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new UserAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
                DatabaseUser user = dbUsersList.get(position);
                    TextView clickedView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterFollowBtn);
                if(view == clickedView) {
                    if (clickedView.getText().equals("following")) {

                        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, " THE CLICK VIEW IS " + clickedView.getText());
                        //APPLY Following
                        String txtFollow = "follow";
                        clickedView.setText(txtFollow);
                        if (user.getIsChanged() == 0) {
                            user.setIsChanged(1);
                        } else {
                            user.setIsChanged(0);
                        }
                        user.setIsType(3);
                        db.updateFollow(user);

                        userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {

                        clickedView.setText("following");
                        if (user.getIsChanged() == 0) {
                            user.setIsChanged(1);
                        } else {
                            user.setIsChanged(0);
                        }
                        user.setIsType(0);
                        db.updateFollow(user);

                        userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.getUsername() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    takeToUserProfile(dbUsersList.get(position));
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the adapter class:

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<DatabaseUser> dbUsersList, followingList;
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private Context context;
    private Typeface typeFace, italicTypeface, boldTypeface;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView userAdapterUsername, userAdapterFollowBtn;
        public ImageView userAdapterUserPicture;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            userAdapterUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterUsername);
            userAdapterFollowBtn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterFollowBtn);
            userAdapterUserPicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterUserPicture);
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "IN MY VIEW HOLDER");

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            userAdapterFollowBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnEntryClickListener != null) {
                Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "IN On click");
                mOnEntryClickListener.onEntryClick(v, getAdapterPosition());


            }
        }
    }
    private static OnEntryClickListener mOnEntryClickListener;

    public interface OnEntryClickListener {
        void onEntryClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnEntryClickListener(OnEntryClickListener onEntryClickListener) {
        mOnEntryClickListener = onEntryClickListener;
    }


    public UserAdapter(Context mContext, List<DatabaseUser> usersList, List<DatabaseUser> passedFollowing, Typeface myTypeface, Typeface myTypefaceItalic, Typeface myTypefaceBold) {
        context = mContext;
        dbUsersList = usersList;
        followingList = passedFollowing;
        typeFace = myTypeface;
        italicTypeface = myTypefaceItalic;
        boldTypeface = myTypefaceBold;
        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "IN MY User ADAPTER CONSTRUCTOR");
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.follow_item, parent, false);
        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "RETURN ITEM VIEW HOLDER");


        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


         DatabaseUser user = dbUsersList.get(position);


        holder.userAdapterUsername.setTypeface(boldTypeface);

        holder.userAdapterUsername.setText(user.getUsername());

        final int pos = getItemViewType(position);
        //TODO Create pic link

        if(containsId(dbUsersList.get(pos), followingList)) {
            //Then show following
            holder.userAdapterFollowBtn.setText("following");


        } else {
            //show follow
            holder.userAdapterFollowBtn.setText("follow");
        }



        String userspic = dbUsersList.get(pos).getPicture();
        if(userspic == null) {
            //SET DEFAULT OR PUT DEFAULT IN XML AND DO NOTHING IT SHOULD SHOW DEFAULT PIC
        } else {
            //TODO setupUser Pic
            String img1 = "http://www.hindustantimes.com/Images/popup/2015/6/kungfu2.jpg";
            Picasso.with(context).load(img1).transform(new RoundedTransformation()).into(holder.userAdapterUserPicture);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dbUsersList.size();
    }

    public static boolean containsId(DatabaseUser currentUser, List<DatabaseUser> list) {
        for (DatabaseUser object : list) {
            if (currentUser.getUserId().equals(object.getUserId())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of implementing OnItemTouchListener, you can implement onClick on parent view of item like implement on button

Comment: Are you telling me to change the onItemTouchListener and have an onClick on the Recycler view and the follow button or an onClick on just the button within the RecyclerView, if so how do I do it without affecting the onItemTouch as you can see  onBindViewHolder I try to implement an onClickListener but does not work?

Comment: How about an `OnClickListener` for each item in the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh How would I implement it, currently having it the way I do in the bindviewHolder is not working

Comment: Take a look at [a Gist I created a while ago](https://gist.github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/226f44657a41c31c486b). It shows how you could implement an `OnClickListener` for each item in your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh so I tried to implement it and disabled my touchlistener in the parent class, but it does not register the clicks, no log print out either, side note getPosition() is depreciated but I updated it with your implementation of it, I see I never setOnEntryClickListener where am I suppose to set that in the bind?

Comment: You do not need to set it in `onBindViewHolder` as the listeners get set in the view holder. When you use your `RecyclerView`, you need to first initialise your adapter. For example: `SimpleListAdapter adapter = new SimpleListAdapter(list);`. Maybe the part you are forgetting is to call the relevant method on the adapter: adapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new OnEntryClickListener ... );`. Finally, you would use `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`. I suspect it is the middle step you may have missed out.

Comment: Ah ok seems to work, only issue I am having now is that I cannot change the actual text of the view... am I doing this wrong? `if(view == view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterFollowBtn)) {  TextView clickedView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterFollowBtn);  if (clickedView.getText().equals("following")) { clickedView.setText("follow");`'  for some reason it is not changing text

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same in this project, go here and copy this itemclicklistener class:
https://github.com/isaacurbina/MyMovies/blob/c985f28311f25522c7907d090e48dab5fc108c01/app/src/main/java/com/mobileappsco/training/mymovies/Listeners/RecyclerItemClickListener.java

Then on your Activity or Fragment do this with your recyclerview object.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // HERE GOES YOUR CODE FOR THE CLICK OF THE ITEM
                    }
                })
        );
```

Then you can use the position to reference the original object inside the list of objects that your adapter is using (the list should be public so that you can access it from the Activity or Fragment), or do like me and put a hidden textview with the ID instead of the position that you can get with:

TextView clickedItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hidden_id_textview);
int id = clickedItem.getText();

You can also check at the whole project that contains the class that I sent you in the link above. I hope it helps.

Kind regards!

Comment: This was not working, giving me a null reference on the user object when using the position

Comment: Yeah here http://pastebin.com/BuT3Avte I didnt want to get things too jumbled up but the click gives me a null object error on user for some reason... where as applying the other code it seems to be fine.

Comment: As I said in the answer, the position is not the ID, therefore you need to go to the adapter.listofobjects.get(position) or attach the ID to the viewholder card (my fav).

Comment: What you are doing is this dbUsersList.get(position) but I think the list here is not related to the one in the Adapter, is it? I assume the code is in your Activity because you are setting the lstener to the recyclerview.

Comment: It is the same list being passed into the adapter, if position gave me a number based on the position of the view within the adapter then I would assume it should be the same place as the list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107296/discussion-between-isaac-urbina-and-lion789).

Comment: This does not work with accessing the subview afterwards.